# BackgroundWorker - Calling thread cannot access object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

So in my DoWork, I have

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, BitmapImage>> Files = new List<KeyValuePair<string,BitmapImage>>((List<KeyValuePair<String, BitmapImage>>)e.Argument);

foreach (KeyValuePair<String, BitmapImage> i in Files)
{
    string temp = i.ToString();               .......(1)
    //.....
}
```

I'm passing the argument as follows :-

```
backgroundWorkerForReupload.RunWorkerAsync(files);
```

where "files" is of Type `List<KeyValuePair<string, BitmapImage>>`

At line (1) above, it throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the message : "*The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.*"

I'm confused as to why `i` is owned by another thread. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How were they loaded? Were they used for anything else? Most likely reason is that they are somehow associated with the main UI thread.

Comment: `e.Argument` is where this is coming from. The argument is coming from the calling thread. Thereby, although you are creating a new list of key value pairs, the data contained in these pairs is not copied, it is referenced, and on another thread. Still doesn't explain why the thread safe call to `ToString` fails.

Comment: @toad the original List is being used in the UI thread but "Files" is created using the new keyword (in the DoWork() method). So shouldn't it be a new copy of the list owned by the background thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most WPF objects, including `BitmapImage`, are thread-affine, and can only be used by the thread they were created on.

You can fix this for `BitmapImage` by calling `Freeze()` first.

Comment: Thank you sir your solution has helped me a lot, actually I been searching for a solution for this problem on this thread :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975709/invalidoperationexception-when-trying-to-access-a-complex-object-from-another-th/23979622#23979622