# InvalidOperationException when trying to access a complex object from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

After I tried lots and lots of solutions I couldn't solve this problem by any means so I started to believe that there is no solution for this problem.

I have an object that contains complex attributes. E.g: `List<SomeComplexObject>`. I am running a method from this class on a worker thread to keep the GUI running until the worker thread finishes. When it finishes execution, I want to use the attributes of these objects to update GUI let's say I want to use `List<SomeComplexObject>` looping through this list and update the GUI. But each time I try to access this list the debugger throws an `InvalidOperationException`: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I tried to make all attributes of this class volatile but with no hope I also used `Lazy<T>` class approach to solve but the same problem occurs.

Class that contain the worker function:

```
public class MainModules
{

    #region Attributes

    public VIDEO video; 

    public string VideoPath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    LowLevelModule lowLevelOutput;

    //this list that I want to use to Update GUI 
    public volatile List<FaceRecognitionModule> faceModuleOutput;

    //worker function running on different thread
     public void RunMainModules()
     {
        //some complex work to set the class attributes
     }
 }
```

Thread creation in GUI class

```
 private void RunMainModules_BtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      //  MainModule = new MainModules(mainModuleObj, Inpath, lif, keyframefolderpath, trdbpath, labelspath, rrankspath, alignmatpath, 11, 10);
        this.LazyMainModule = new Lazy<MainModules>(this.InitLazyMainModule);
        MainModuleThread = new Thread(this.RunMainModules);
        MainModuleThread.Start(MainModule);

    }

    public MainModules InitLazyMainModule()
    {
        return new MainModules(mainModuleObj, Inpath, lif, keyframefolderpath, trdbpath, labelspath, rrankspath, alignmatpath, 11, 10);
    }
     public void RunMainModules(Object obj)
    {
        //MainModules mm = obj as MainModules;
        MainModules mm = LazyMainModule.Value;
        mm.RunMainModules();
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            this.InitSpeechRec_Btn.IsEnabled = true;
        }));
    }
```

When I try to access `faceModuleOutput` in class `MainModules` from GUI I got `InvalidOperationException`.

```
Image img = new Image();
//InvalidOperationException occurs here
img.Source = LazyMainModule.Value.faceModuleOutput[0].keyframes[1].keyframe;
```

To brief this post:
I want to access an object instantiated by a background thread from main thread but it throws

```
InvalidOperationException : The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Comment: What is the excat message of the `InvalidOperationException` ?

Comment: Check the exception for more details about what invalid thing is happening

Comment: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Comment: Wait, is this a UI element you're trying to access?

Comment: yes I am trying to assign an object returned from worker thread to a UI element

Comment: This is illegal, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution ... Class `BitmapImage` is thread-affine so it can't be accessed by multiple threads you need first to make it opened for reading only closed for writing so the compiler can guarantee that no threads will modify it's content

So the solution ... :

```
 //keyframe here is a BitmapImage so on creation we must call keyframe.Freeze()
 LazyMainModule.Value.faceModuleOutput[0].keyframes[1].keyframe;
```

class `KeyFrame`:

```
public class KeyFrame
{
    public volatile BitmapImage keyframe;
    public volatile List<string> personsNames;
    public volatile List<string> categories;

    public KeyFrame(BitmapImage keyframe, List<string> personsNames, List<string> categories)
    {
        this.keyframe = keyframe;
        //here we call Freeze funcition on creation to make it modifiable 
        this.keyframe.Freeze();
        this.personsNames = personsNames;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A UI control needs to be created/modified from the GUI Thread. Doing otherwise is illegal.

It seems that the `MainModuleThread` is (at least) creating and modifying an `Image` . This should be done in the GUI Thread (the one that called `RunMainModules_BtnClick`)

Comment: Sir, this is what I actually do all GUI updating code runs from main thread but it uses an object created by another thread to perform the update

Comment: Yes, this is illegal. Do it th other way : the GUI Thread performs itself the update.

Comment: How do I suppose to do that ? since the data used to update GUI results from a background worker

Comment: this post will answer your last question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Comment: Sir, this post explains how to update a UI element from another thread which isn't I want to do. Now I am on MainThread and I want to update a UI element using an object created by another thread

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify or even access pretty much anything that relates to the UI thread from another thread. This can get pretty extreme/annoying sometimes because you can't even get the value in a textbox or check if a checkbox is checked or not. If you want to perform an action on an object owned by the UI thread you need to invoke the UI thread to do it.

```
UIObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
   //[Perform your action in here]
  });
```

Comment: I'm not trying to access a UI element from another thread, I'm trying to access an object created by another thread from Main Thread

Comment: Same exception occurs since class attributes are created on the background thread